# Signed URL for JW Player doesn't expire

Tags: jwplayer

So, I use the following script (simplified) to render a script tag with a signed JW Player Link. The expiry date of the link should be 10 seconds (for testing only).

```
<?php
/**
 * generates a signed URL for JW Player
 *
 **/
function _getSignedUrl($path, $secret, $timeout = 3600, $domain = 'content.jwplatform.com') {
    $expires = time() + $timeout;
    $signature = md5($path . ':' . $expires . ':' . $secret);
    return 'http://' . $domain . '/' . $path . '?exp=' . $expires . '&sig=' . $signature;
}

echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . _getSignedUrl('players/foo-bar.js', 'mYsEcReT1234', 10) . '"></script>';
?>
```

The Player plays the video just fine when I set the timeout to >1 and doesn't play it when I set the timeout to <1 (Permission denied). So far, so good. But when I copy the rendered script tag from the DOM (with a timeout of e.g. 10 seconds) and put it in a static HTML file and load the page after the link should be expired, the video still plays. Where am I thinking wrong?

EDIT: Here's an example link (timeout was 3600):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/players/rUqzk7Ff-JGyYovz4.js?exp=1484053682&amp;sig=269e796e58824711b32b2dc47c574cd8"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have any link for this

Comment: Sure, I added it in the description

Comment: please add one more link which is working, this one says "Permission denied"

Comment: Hm, looks like it expired, but it took definetly more than 10 seconds... I replaced it with a newer one

Comment: can you create new one?

Comment: Ok, looks like the expireation actually works, but the calculatiin is somehow inaccurate. I replaced it with a link that has a timeout of 3600. My guess would be that the expiration date is rounded to a minute

Comment: yes it has minimum value, i too guess the same. explore more about minimum value you can give for link expiration in timeout.It might help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132790/discussion-between-hitesh-and-biedert).

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: If that's so important for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a minimum timeout set in your server.

> $timeout
>
> - The time in seconds you want the signed URL to remain valid, e.g. "3600".
> - Typical timeouts are between a minute and a few hours. Default is "3600".
> - **Make sure the time on your server is set correctly, or URLs with short timeouts will fail!**

**`For More information`**

> https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1433647-url-token-signing
>
> https://support-static.jwplayer.com/API/php-example.txt

Found another interesting article on this - http://oriolrius.cat/blog/2015/08/12/secure-download-urls-with-expiration-time/ which may be helpful.